# text widget wordpress 4.8

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-4.8

The new Text Widget in WordPress 4.8 is stripping out code.
For example, if the following code is placed in the widget via the Text editor:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="location"></a>List 1</li>
<li><a href="#" class="location"></a>List 2</li>
</ul>
```

Just noticed the issue this morning, after upgrading to WP 4.8 on a few sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to happen with Wordpress 4.8. [Here](https://www.blogaid.net/wordpress-4-8-text-widget-meltdown/) is an article regarding this issue.

As long as you don't open a text widget, you should be safe from this behavior.

One solution is to use a plugin available named [Classic Text Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-text-widget/) that fixes this issue. Note that this plugin uses PHP namespaces which are only supported in PHP Version 5.3.0 and higher.

Comment: I unfortunately ran into this issue AFTER updating, so I have no way to dump my widget content into another type of widget before updating. I x=will test Classic Text Widget. Thanks.